# Prevent javascript access to DOM elements of widget

Tags: javascript

If I develop a Javascript widget that others can embed directly into their page without using an iFrame, is it somehow possible to prevent Javascript access to DOM-elements of the widget from the embedding page?

Suppose the widget is an image gallery and the embedding website selects all images via Javascript and changes both CSS attributes and any click handlers. How can I prevent the functionality or appearance of the widget from being changed without using an iFrame? I imagine this as a kind of firewall that allows/blocks Javascript access by DOM-source and destination.

Comment: No it is not possible. The DOM doesn't have any mechanisms for that. If your stuff is part of the page DOM, anything that can access the DOM can access your elements.

Comment: You're manipulating the websites DOM, not vice versa. You are a guest on their website.

Comment: One odd idea - manipulate the DOM inside a private closure, then render the result with something like html2canvas. Though, interactivity would be much more difficult, and the underlying elements could still be seen if the page hijacks DOM methods before your script runs. I wouldn't bother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The perfect solution is [Shadow Dom](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/)